# Templatize downcasting to the derived class and call the corresponding method

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, smart-pointers

I have a routine in the main.cpp where user will specify which mode to execute in the program. Once the mode is specified, the corresponding block will be executed - first downcast the parent solver to the child solver and call the associated `solve` method in the child class.

```cpp
    std::unique_ptr<SudokuSolver> solver;
    if (mode == MODES::SEQUENTIAL_BACKTRACKING) 
    {
        solver = std::make_unique<SudokuSolver_SequentialBacktracking>();
        SudokuSolver_SequentialBacktracking* child_solver = dynamic_cast<SudokuSolver_SequentialBacktracking*>(solver.get());
        child_solver->solve(board);
    } 
    else if (mode == MODES::SEQUENTIAL_BRUTEFORCE)
    {
        solver = std::make_unique<SudokuSolver_SequentialBruteForce>();
        SudokuSolver_SequentialBruteForce* child_solver = dynamic_cast<SudokuSolver_SequentialBruteForce*>(solver.get());
        child_solver->solve(board);
    }   
    else if (mode == MODES::PARALLEL_BRUTEFORCE)
    {
        int NUM_THREADS = (argc >= 5) ? std::stoi(argv[4]) : 2;
        omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);
        
        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            #pragma omp single nowait
            {
                solver = std::make_unique<SudokuSolver_ParallelBruteForce>();
                SudokuSolver_ParallelBruteForce* child_solver = dynamic_cast<SudokuSolver_ParallelBruteForce*>(solver.get());
                child_solver->solve(board);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (mode == MODES::SEQUENTIAL_DANCINGLINKS)
    {
        solver = std::make_unique<SudokuSolver_SequentialDLX>(board);
        SudokuSolver_SequentialDLX* child_solver = dynamic_cast<SudokuSolver_SequentialDLX*>(solver.get());
        child_solver->solve();
    }
    else if (mode == MODES::PARALLEL_DANCINGLINKS)
    {
        int NUM_THREADS = (argc >= 5) ? std::stoi(argv[4]) : 2;
        omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);

        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            #pragma omp single
            {
                solver = std::make_unique<SudokuSolver_ParallelDLX>(board);
                SudokuSolver_ParallelDLX* child_solver = dynamic_cast<SudokuSolver_ParallelDLX*>(solver.get());
                child_solver->solve();
            }
        }
    }
```

I found it's kinda duplicates of code so I want to templatize them to something like:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void downCastandSolve(std::unique_ptr<SudokuSolver> solver, SudokuBoard& board)
{
    solver = std::make_unique<T>(board);
    T* child_solver = dynamic_cast<T*>(solver.get());
    child_solver->solve();
}
```

However, I got the following error message:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = SudokuSolver; _Dp = std::default_delete<SudokuSolver>]’
```

Not sure how to properly templatize the portions of code. Hope someone could help!

Comment: It look like you could replace the need of `dynamic_cast` by making `solve` function virtual...  Also, it seems that `std::unique_ptr<SudokuSolver> solver` is not really useful as it is never used and only make remaining code more complicated by adding extra casts...

Comment: Does `solver` get used subsequent to this branching code?  Because as @Phil1970 says, the code without it is very simple: `T(board).solve();`

Comment: @Phil1970 @Ben Voigt Yes, ```solver``` is used after the branching code to access the solution stored in the ```SudokuSolver``` class by ```solver->get_solution()```. That's why I need to downcast here. But I hope there is better suggestion for my design...

Comment: Obviously `auto child_solver = std::make_unique<T>(board); child_solver->solve(); solver = std::move(child_solver);` would avoid the useless cast without any other changes.
`

Comment: Parallel code also seems suspicious as there are no loop or way to combine results...

Comment: @Phil1970 The parallel code is implemented in the associated ```solve``` method in the child class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have much clearer code if `solve` function was virtual.

Also, either the constructor or the solve method should receive the board reference but not both. Having a single way make the code simpler to understand as each algorithm works the same way.

```
std::unique_ptr<SudokuSolver> CreateSolver(MODES mode)
{
    switch (mode)
    {
        case MODES::SEQUENTIAL_BACKTRACKING:
            return std::make_unique<SudokuSolver_SequentialBacktracking>();
        ...
    }
}
```

Then assuming `solve` is virtual, the code resume to:

```
auto solver = CreateSolver(mode);
solver->solve(board);
solver->get_solution();
```

Any parallel stuff should be hidden inside the `solve` function when appropriate.

By writing code like that, it is much easier to read and you don't need an extra template function to share code as you avoid duplication from the start.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. It makes my code much easier to read and understand indeed. :)

Answer (score 4):

`std::unique_ptr`s are not copyable. You need to take it by reference:

```
void downCastandSolve(std::unique_ptr<SudokuSolver>& solver, SudokuBoard& board)
//                                                 ^
```